# How do I unwrap array object from JsSuccess

Tags: arrays, scala, play-json

I am validating a json against a model and then trying to extract array element from it but I am not sure how to unwrap array object.

Here is sample code

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Person(fName: String, lName: String, age: Int, coins: Array[String])

val p1 = Json.parse("""
{
  "fName" : "John",
  "lName" : "Smith",
  "age" :  21,
  "coins": ["five", "ten"]
  }
""")

implicit val personReads: Reads[Person] = (
  (JsPath \ "fName").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "lName").read[String] and
    (JsPath \ "age").read[Int] and
    (JsPath \ "coins").read[Array[String]]
  )(Person.apply _)


val result = p1.validate[Person]

p1.validate[Person] match {
  case s: JsSuccess[Person] => println("success", s.value.coins)
  case _ => println("fail")
}
```

Note that the output of `println` is

`(success,[Ljava.lang.String;@720f4e76)`

I am sure I am missing something very basic. How can I print coins as `["five", "ten"]` ?

Comment: Yeah do not use plain **Arrays** use a real collection like **List**.

Comment: thanks, works when I use List or Seq, do you know why this is the case?

Comment: Yes, is very simple actually. That is how the `toString` of an area works it shows an abbreviation of the class inside the array and then the array memory address. Why? Because freaking Java. That is just one of the reasons why you should just stay away of Arrays and use proper collections instead. - BTW, a final note that you can use `mkString` to format the output as you want.